# utl_lms.format_message not working with sql insert

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please let me know if I am missing anything here as below sql insert query has an issue as its not executing:

```
 v_sql_insert := utl_lms.format_message('insert into st_spreadsheet_action (storage_id, action_date, created_by, active, DATE_DUE, ASSIGNMENT_YN, COORDINATOR_COM, PROCESSOR_COM) values (''%s'', ''%s'', ''%s'', ''%s'', ''%s'', ''%s'', ''%s'', ''%s'') ', V('P11_ROW_PK'), V('P11_ACTION_DATE'), V('P11_CREATED_BY'), V('P11_ACTIVE'), V('P11_DATE_DUE'), V('P11_ASSIGNMENT_COMP'), REPLACE(V('P11_COORDINATOR'), '''', ''''''), REPLACE(V('P11_PROCESSOR'), '''', ''''''));`
`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_insert;
```

Comment: What is `V` in your code ?

Comment: Is there any error or failure message ?

Comment: V is fetching values from Item fields, and there is no error but data is not getting saved into DB table @Sujitmohanty30

Comment: Could you check sql%rowcount right after the execute immediate ? it will tell you how many records inserted.

Comment: If an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement doesn't raise an exception then it must have worked. Is the code missing a commit?

Comment: sqlcount was not working because of constraint on the column of table

Comment: Code is correct, one column having constraint was missing in insertion ans so query wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is correct, one column having constraint was missing in insertion ans so query wasn't working.